# How to get all listing details through ebay API?

Tags: ebay-api

I'm using ebay API request: "GetSellerListRequest" with option "ReturnAll".
It gives me a bunch of information, but there is missing some, like (Return policy or Shipping policy and a few others).

In other words, how i can pull information from ebay, which later i could automatically post listings to ebay with "AddFixedPriceItemRequest" ?

Comment: What does your question have to do with php? + their API is well documented

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GetItem** call from eBay trading API and set the value of DetailLevel element as RETURN ALL. This would return the data that you want to Return, shipping details etc.